# Delete excel table column

Tags: excel

I have a `table` in excel with 10 columns. I need to delete `column 5`, so I select it, right-click, and select Delete , Delete Table Columns. Excel returns the error "This operation is not valid. The operation is attempting to shift cells in a table on your worksheet". Any ideas on how I can delete it? Responses in other forums said you need to convert the table to a range first, but I'd like to avoid doing that if possible so it doesn't mess up my formulas.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you have merged some cells in one of the Rows.
If that is the case, just un-merge the cells -> Delete the columns -> merge the cells again.